# ngrinder-Performance Testing Tool Throws exception

Tags: performance-testing

I need some clear steps to install ngrinder,A Performance testing tool.

Even though I followed the steps in the following link, I am not able to setup the environment in my machine.

Visit Here for installation steps.

http://www.cubrid.org/wiki_ngrinder/entry/ngrinder-devzone

So, Please help me to sort out this problem to setup the environment to do the performance testing using ngrinder.

Comment: Hi, welcome on SO. Please help us understand where you are, what you tried, where the next problem is etc.

Comment: Hi, I download the ngrinder-controller.war file in the following link. The Link is [[ https://sourceforge.net/projects/ngrinder/files/ ]]. the version of that war file is 3.3.  There are several steps given in the following link to setup environment and install the ngrinder performance testing tool. the installation guide link is [[  http://www.cubrid.org/wiki_ngrinder/entry/installation-guide ]]  I follwed these steps to install it. but these is a lot of exception thrown by the application while I was running in the cmd prompt. If you visit those link, you can get idea to help me.